# Update a Nested Array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have many company documents like this:

```
{
 "name" : "testCompany",
 "code" : "150",
 "access" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "x",
        "role" : "admin"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "y",
        "role" : "User"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "z",
        "role" : "User"
    }
   ]
 }
```

I want to find a company which has the code value of '150'. And then remove the access with name of 'z'. I wrote this, but it didn't work. I don't get any errors:

```
collection.update(
{code: req.body.companyCode }, 
{$pull: {"access.$.name":  req.body.username}}, 
function(err, results) {
                res.send({error: err, affected: results});
                db.close();
            });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with node, but I think it should be:

```
collection.update(
{code: req.body.companyCode }, 
{$pull: {"access": {"name": req.body.username}}}, 
function(err, results) {
                res.send({error: err, affected: results});
                db.close();
            });
```